# Can't get my form data to send to my email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm trying to get all the data entered into the form on my website sent to my email when submitted, but just can't seem to get it to work...

This is my email.php file..

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "dcmagpies@hotmail.co.uk";
$EmailTo = "  dcmagpies@hotmail.co.uk";
$Subject = "online form message";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['feedback']));
// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
echo "please check your details";
header("");
exit;
}

// prepare email body text

$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page
if ($success){
print "Thankyou"

}
?>
```

My html code...

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="emailphp.php">
    <table width="450px">
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <label for="name">Name *</label>
</td>
    <td valign="top">
    <input  type="text" name="Name" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

    <td valign="top"">

    <label for="email">Email *</label>
</td>
    <td valign="top">
    <input  type="text" name="Email" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <label for="feedback">Feedback *</label>
</td>
    <td valign="top">
    <input  type="text" name="Feedback" maxlength="150" size="30">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

When i test it, after i enter some data in the form and submit it, it just shows the php code in the browser.

Comment: where is your form start tag?

Comment: "just show PHP Code"??? Is PHP installed on your webserver (and the file named *.php)

Comment: <form name="contactform" method="post" action="emailphp.php">

this is the form start tag... didnt realise it wasnt entered in above.

Comment: Do you have `php` and `web server` installed on your local machine?

Comment: Configure your server to run PHP scripts first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure

- check you saved php file in .php type
- put `echo $EmailTo.$Subject.$Body;die;` if it shows values correct, you a problem in mail function line.
- try like this `"From: <".$EmailFrom.">"` in mail function line.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the values like this

```
$Name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name']));
$Email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']));
$Message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['Feedback']));
```

as you have given the names starting with capital letter in the form.